# $d(\bigcup_{i=1}A_i, \bigcup_{i=1}B_i)\leq \sum\limits_{i}d(A_i,B_i)$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu:\mathcal {E} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ be additive and regular.

Show that for countable families of subsets $A_i, B_i \subset \mathbb{R}^d, i \in \mathbb{N}:$

$$d(\bigcup_{i}A_i, \bigcup_{i}B_i)\leq  \sum\limits_{i}d(A_i,B_i)$$

Comment: What does $\mu$ have to do with the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$d(A, B \cup C) \le \min\{d(A,B), d(A,C)\} \le  d(A,B) + d(A,C)$$

Comment: @BrianMoehring Using $d(A, B \cup C) \le d(A,B) + d(A,C)$ yields $d(\bigcup_j A_j, \bigcup_i B_i) \le \sum_i d(\bigcup_j A_j, B_i)$. Using $d(A, B\cup C) \le \min\{d(A,B), d(A,C)\} \le d(A,B)$ implies $d(\bigcup_j A_j, B_i) \le d(A_i, B_i)$.

Comment: Thanks.  But now I'm even more bothered by the goal of the question.  The sum ought to be replaced by the infimum, or just the first term...